# Can transactions with only 1 gwei gas price still succeed (confirmed) in 2021?

Tags: transactions, gas, fees, confirmations

https://ethgasstation.info (now https://archive.is/wip/Zemix) showing

> Lowest gas price (gwei)
>
> 0
>
> 6

Does that mean it is still possible to have transactions with only 1 gwei gas price confirmed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is still possible.

Miners choose what transactions they wish to mine. Usually they choose to mine transactions that have the higher gas price in order to earn the most out of fees but they have no obligation to.

Answer (score 0):

Possible, but **extremely unlikely** unless you have a "connection" to a miner.  This means being a miner or being "friends" with a miner that has decided to mine your transaction instead of a more profitable transaction.

An alternative is [How are 0 gas price transactions getting mined?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/93668/how-are-0-gas-price-transactions-getting-mined)