# How are 0 gas price transactions getting mined?

Tags: transactions, gas, fees, flashbots

Here's a transaction with a gas price of 0:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbdda3e1d4d879590b5d21ce777a91573fb5bbb40fa0f6cbcc8420a6d3d208668

How is it getting mined?  Is the miner mining it for free?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is that the miner was paid (0.011111111111111 Ether) in the next transaction.

#### Brief details

This worked because a specific miner was sent 2 transactions off-chain.

The transaction in question is the 1st transaction in block 11649597
https://etherscan.io/txs?block=11649597&p=4

Look at the 2nd transaction in the block
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xeb267d95fbfb241c76507430a96fbbd321c9a4316c916f69d3825e5572f758d6

You will see that the ether sent in the contract ends up paying the miner at 0xd224ca0c819e8e97ba0136b3b95ceff503b79f53

https://etherscan.io/block/11649597 you can see is mined by 0xd224ca0c819e8e97ba0136b3b95ceff503b79f53

Additional source: https://twitter.com/epheph/status/1357089183601483777

Comment: An interesting public implementation of MEV, thanks! Here's a quick link to the underlying service also: https://github.com/flashbots/pm/blob/main/guides/flashbots-alpha.md